# How to get the last number of a string using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

1 - 2 of 2

Above is my text. This is from paging of a web application. How do i extract the last number of the above text. SO i will get the count of list in that page and i can run a loop with respect to the number.

Comment: Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Comment: actually im stuck. Im not able to make find code itself.

String pageCount = countOfDelegator.getText(); //took the text to string
char lastnumber = pageCount.charAt(pageCount.length() - 1);  //Got last character. 

But this is not working as expected. output of pageCount is 1 - 2 of 2

Comment: Where are you stuck? Have you written any code? Does your code executes? Are you facing any error? Consider updating your question with your `code block` & `error stack trace`. Thanks

Comment: Nope. I dont have code. Im looking for code. 

My requirement is, i need to run my script in a loop with respect to the count of rows in a table. So, what i planned is, get the count of rows from pagination option (ie, 1 - 2 of 2 . Means table is displayed 1 to 2 rows out of total 2 rows. ). Now i need to take the last digit 2 as count of  total rows and run script (for loop) that much time.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow.com is not a Code Writing agency/service. You may consider getting your code written by some professional Code Writing Agency. Thanks

Comment: hahaha... thats cool..  i didnt ask for full code.. just wanna know is it possible to extract the last number of a string. Consider "1 - 2 of 2" as my string and how do i get 2 from the string.

Comment: Yes, it is possible through pure`Java` and `Python` both. But how does it relates to #selenium or #selenium-webdriver? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring`

Let's consider your example. You have a String `1 - 2 of 2` (pagination probably)
Each of individual character is a specified index of a String

1 = 0
space = 1
 - = 2
space = 3 
etc.

`String` has a set of methods to perform various tasks. One of them is `length()` which gives you number of characters in your `String`

What you can do is to pass your length of String to substring.

Example:
`myString.substring(0,1)` will give you results of `1`
`myString.substring(0,myString.length())` wil give you results of `1 - 2 of 5`

Additional info: myString.length() is an `int` type so you can perform math operations like `+` or `-`
`myString.substring(0,myString.length()-1)` will give you results of `1 - 2 of`

I gave you the tools, now it's time for you to find the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string using the spaces and then grab the last element of the split array. That should cover you even if the last number has more than one digit. Throw in a trim, just in case, to remove any leading/trailing white space.

```
String[] splitter = pageCount.trim().split(" ");
System.out.println(splitter[splitter.length - 1]);
```